# I get a cryptic error when searching for venue

Tags: api, eventbrite

When I search for a specific venue (id: 1515239)

https://www.eventbrite.com/json/venue_get?app_key=EHHWMU473LTVEO4JFY&id=1515239

I get the following error/response, not sure what it means:

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_type": "Not Found",
    "error_message": "Invalid email and/or password."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Venue information is considered private data.
You probably need to include some additional user credentials in your request.

See http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/